# ajax upload picture without refresh, How to get back an error if something when wrong

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I use Ajax to upload a picture without a refresh. But for some reason error messages like *the file is too big* doesn't get shown. If everything goes well and there are no errors it all works fine and I get a message saying it worked. I tried it the following 2 ways:

```
form_data.append('file', file_data);
$.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php',
            dataType: 'json', 
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,                         
            type: 'post',
            success: function(response){
                if (response.errors == 0){
                     //do something to show it went well
                }
                else{
                     //do something to show it went wrong
                }
           }
```

Then after some while I realized that the above was probably wrong since it only acts if the upload is a succes. So I tried this instead:

```
            success: function(response){
                //do something to show it went well
           },
           error: function(response){
                //do something to show it went wrong
                }
```

But this doesn't work either

The script that uploads the pictures looks like this:

```
   if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 5000000) {
        echo json_encode(array('errors'=>1,'naam_orgineel'=>$_FILES['file']['name'], 'errormsg'=>'file size is to big'));
        $$errors = 1;
    }

   if ($errors == 0){
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target);

   echo json_encode(array('errors'=>0,'naam_orgineel'=>$_FILES['file']     ['name'], 'naam'=>$target_file));
   }
```

Does anyone know why error messages don't get shown in both ways?

Comment: You have $$errors and $errors. You never set the error messages since $error is not set

Answer (score 0):

Try with a response fail

```
var request = $.ajax({
  ......
});

request.done(function( msg ) {
  ....
});

request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```